# Replace empty string with text using sed or similar tool

Tags: bash, sed, replace

Is it possible to replace an *empty string* with some text using `sed` or similar tool?

```
sed 's/^$/sometext/'
```

will match an *empty line* but that is not what I am looking for. I thought that

```
sed 's//sometext/'
```

would work but that does not seem to be the case.

---

In this particular case I wish to detect a `grep` without a match.

```
echo 'hi' | grep 'sam' | ...
```

Comment: "Replace empty string" – In any place of a string (empty or not) you can detect *any number* of empty substrings. Do you want to replace them *all*? :)

Comment: It was my thinking that lets say `printf ''` or a `grep` without a match would output a null character and that I could use some command to detect and replace this.

Comment: This feels like an XY question: can we peel back the onion and figure out *why* you would want something like this?

Comment: In this specific case I wish to detect a `grep` without a match.

Comment: "I wish to detect a `grep` without a match." – In case there is a match, do you need to store or process it? If not, the standard way is to check the *exit status* of `grep -q`. Example: `echo hi | if ! grep -q sam; then echo 'no match'; fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was my thinking that lets say `printf ''` or a `grep` without a match would output a null character and that I could use some command to detect and replace this.

Both `printf ''` and a `grep` that doesn't match anything will output at total number of zero bytes. That's different from one NUL (`\0`) byte, and if there are no bytes, there's nothing to replace as such.

We can't use a regex matching a zero-length string, as those would usually match between every single character, e.g. `printf 'foo\n' | sed -E 's/.{0}/X/g'` would print `XfXoXoX`. (also `sed -e 's//.../'` doesn't work at all since in sed the empty regex means to reuse the previous one.)

We'll have to detect the empty input some other way.

The AWK script below would copy all input lines to output, and if there were none, print `new text`:

```
$ printf '' | awk '1; END { if (NR == 0) printf "new text\n"; }'
new text
$ printf 'xxx\nyyy' | awk '1; END { if (NR == 0) printf "new text\n"; }'
xxx
yyy
```

(`NR` contains the number of "records" in the input, in practice lines. This will add the trailing newline to the last line if it's missing it.)

Answer (score 3):

To replace an empty line, you need to feed `sed` with an empty line.

An empty line is a newline character by itself.  This can be produced by either `echo` or `printf '\n'`.

```bash
$ printf '\n' | sed 's/^$/sometext/'
sometext
```

```bash
$ echo | sed 's/^$/sometext/'
sometext
```

Note that this would replace *all* empty lines in the input, no matter if other lines are non-empty.

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' "line 1" "" "line 3" | sed 's/^$/sometext/'
line 1
sometext
line 3
```

If you want to detect empty input and inject a string, then you may use `ifne` from the moreutils package, with its `-n` option:

```bash
$ printf '' | ifne -n echo sometext
sometext
```

Here, `echo sometext` would be executed only if `ifne` does not detect any input on its standard input stream.  If the left-hand side of the pipeline *does* produce data, that data would be outputted instead.

```bash
$ printf 'hello\n' | ifne -n echo sometext
hello
```

---

As for your additional bit about detecting no match with `grep`:

```bash
echo 'hi' | grep -q 'sam' || echo no match
```

or, with `if` and `then` in place of the short-circuit logic,

```bash
if ! echo 'hi' | grep -q 'sam'; then
    echo no match
fi
```

This uses `grep` with its `-q` option, which causes the utility to be quite and instead only signals a successful or unsuccessful match using its exit status.  If thee is no match, it will exit with a non-zero exit status, and the code above detects this and executes `echo no match`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Kamil Maciorowski in a comment one could, in the specific case of `grep`, parse it's *exit code* instead of it's *stdout*:

```
$ echo 'hi' | grep 'bye' || echo 'sam'
sam
```

This would also allow processing any occuring match:

```
$ echo 'hi' | grep 'hi' || echo 'sam'
hi
```

In case you wish to suppress matches use `grep`'s `-q` option:

```
$ echo 'hi' | grep -q 'hi' || echo 'sam'
```